Simulating data from a piecewise pdf occasionally returns an error
In the following code, I generate data from a piecewise PDF. Usually, I get a sample size of ns, but sometimes I get an error message:

Error: RandomVariate::unsdst: The first argument 30 is not a valid distribution.

Why is that and how can I fix my code?
at = 5;
ns = 30;
Array[y, ns];
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
  Piecewise[{{(0.775/at)*Exp[-1.35*x/at], 
     0 < x <= at}, {.2*(at^.35)/x^1.35, x > at}}], {x, 0, Infinity}]
data = RandomVariate[dist, ns];
data = Flatten[data];
y = Sort[data]


It's a bug introduced in version 14.1, as mentioned in the duplicated question.

I wonder if the fact that CDF[dist, \[Infinity]] is 0.99668 rather than 1 has anything to do with it.

@JimB, unfortunately, including Method -> "Normalize" to ProbabilityDistribution doesn't solve the issue ...
